# Send Worksheets as pdf with outlook

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am in no way a VBA expert so I looked for a code to send worksheets in an excel file to different recipients  by email.

I used this code and this worked well for me, if I want to send the file as excel.

```
Sub MailVersand()

Dim OL As Object
Dim IsCreated As Boolean
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim aWb As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim An As String
Dim Cc As String
Dim From As String
Dim Subject As String
Dim Dpfad As String
Dim Body As String
Dim clc

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
With Application
    clc = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set OL = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err Then
    Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    IsCreated = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0

For Each Ws In Wb.Worksheets
    Ws.Copy
    Set aWb = ActiveWorkbook
    aWb.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".xlsx"
    Dpfad = aWb.FullName
    An = aWb.Worksheets(1).Range("AB2").Value
    Cc = aWb.Worksheets(1).Range("AF2").Value
    Body = aWb.Worksheets(1).Range("AB5").Value
    From = aWb.Worksheets(1).Range("AB4").Value
    Subject = aWb.Worksheets(1).Range("AB3").Value
    aWb.Close True
    With OL.CreateItem(0)
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = From
        .To = An
        .Cc = Cc
        .Body = Body
        .Subject = Subject
        .Attachments.Add Dpfad
        .Send
    End With
    Kill Dpfad
    Set aWb = Nothing
Next

If IsCreated Then OL.Quit
With Application
    .Calculation = cld
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
Set OL = Nothing
Set Wb = Nothing
Set Ws = Nothing
```

End Sub

I have now tried to change this code, so that the file I attached is a pdf file. This proved to be rather difficult but in the end I (almost) managed it.

```
Sub PDFMailVersand()

Dim OL As Object
Dim IsCreated As Boolean
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim aWb As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim An As String
Dim Cc As String
Dim From As String
Dim Subject As String
Dim Dpfad As String
Dim Body As String
Dim strDateiname As String
Dim clc

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
With Application
    clc = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set OL = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err Then
    Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    IsCreated = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0

For Each Ws In Wb.Worksheets
    Ws.Copy
    Set aWb = ActiveWorkbook
    strDateiname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strDateiname, _
                     IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
                     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                     OpenAfterPublish:=False
    An = aWb.Worksheets(1).Range("AB2").Value
    Cc = aWb.Worksheets(1).Range("AF2").Value
    Body = aWb.Worksheets(1).Range("AB5").Value
    From = aWb.Worksheets(1).Range("AB4").Value
    Subject = aWb.Worksheets(1).Range("AB3").Value
    aWb.Close True
    With OL.CreateItem(0)
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = From
        .To = An
        .Cc = Cc
        .Body = Body
        .Subject = Subject
        .Attachments.Add strDateiname
        .Send
    End With
    Kill strDateiname
    Set aWb = Nothing
Next

If IsCreated Then OL.Quit
With Application
    .Calculation = cld
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
Set OL = Nothing
Set Wb = Nothing
Set Ws = Nothing
```

End Sub

But my problem is that now that for each worksheet I get prompt to save the file. How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are closing just after you send the document, The code below should work.

The display alerts is turned off so you are not asked to save the workbook, but then this is enabled again when the workbook is closed.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```